# Generate opaque pointer in C using rusty-cheddar

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I'm trying to generate C header file for a library written in Rust using the [rusty-cheddar crate](https://crates.io/crates/rusty-cheddar).

Here is the definition and implementation of the struct in Rust:

```
pub struct AccountDatabase {
    money: HashMap<String, u32>,
}

impl AccountDatabase {
    fn new() -> AccountDatabase {
        AccountDatabase {
            money: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

If I place `#[repr(C)]` before the struct, rusty-cheddar generates the following declaration of the struct in C

```c
typedef struct AccountDatabase {
    HashMap money;
} AccountDatabase;
```

The `HashMap` is not known to C, therefore I'd like for the struct to be declared as an opaque pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is specified right on the [readme](https://github.com/Sean1708/rusty-cheddar#opaque-structs) file:

> To define an opaque struct you must define a public newtype which is marked as `#[repr(C)]`.

Thus:

```
struct AccountDatabase {
    money: HashMap<String, u32>,
}

impl AccountDatabase {
    fn new() -> AccountDatabase {
        AccountDatabase {
            money: HashMap::new()
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Crate_AccountDatabase(AccountDatabase);
```

(or with some other struct naming of your choice)